# error when using malloc() and free() function

Tags: c, string, malloc

i want to create my own `strcpy()`function without `include <string.h>`.i have read that whenever we call `malloc()` function to allocate memory,we must freeing the memory that we have allocate using `free()`function,but why this program give me a strange error,i never seen this type of error before and why this program doesn't give me the exact destination string.

this is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *my_gets(char *string);
char *coppy(char *dest,char*src);
int len(char *string);

int main (void){
    char *src,*dest;

    src=(char *)malloc(len(src)+1);
    printf("enter string source:");my_gets(src);

    printf("length source=%d\n",len(src));

    dest=(char *)malloc(len(src)+1);
    coppy(dest,src);
    printf("destination string:%s\n",dest);

    free(src);
    free(dest);
    return 0;
}

char *my_gets(char *string){
   char ch;

   while((*string=getchar()) !='\n'){
        string++;
   }
   if(string[len(string)-1]=='\n'){
    string[len(string)-1]='\0';
    }
    return string;
 }

char *coppy(char *dest,char *src){
   while(*src!='\0'){
    *dest++=*src++;
   }
   *dest='\0';
   return dest;
 }

int len(char *string){
   int i=0;

   while(*string!='\0'){
    string++;
    i++;
   }
   return i;
 }
```

this the error :

```
enter string source:i want to create my own strcpy function but i got an a strange error
length source=67
destination string:i want to crI
*** Error in `./program': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x086b4018 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x767e2)[0xb76457e2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77530)[0xb7646530]
./program[0x804855f]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0xb75e8935]
```

./program[0x80483d1] 
    ======= Memory map: ========
    08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4330274     /home/harianja/LUNDU/Lundu/coding/Cprogram/program
   08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 4330274    /home/harianja/LUNDU/Lundu/coding/Cprogram/program
    0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 4330274         /home/harianja/LUNDU/Lundu/coding/Cprogram/program
    086b4000-086d5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
    b7593000-b75ae000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4195166    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    b75ae000-b75af000 r--p 0001a000 08:01 4195166    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    b75af000-b75b0000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 4195166    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    b75ce000-b75cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    b75cf000-b777d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4208177    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
    b777d000-b777f000 r--p 001ae000 08:01 4208177    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
    b777f000-b7780000 rw-p 001b0000 08:01 4208177    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
    b7780000-b7783000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    b779e000-b77a3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    b77a3000-b77a4000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
    b77a4000-b77c4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4208178    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
    b77c4000-b77c5000 r--p 0001f000 08:01 4208178    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
    b77c5000-b77c6000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 4208178    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
    bf863000-bf884000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
    Aborted

Comment: If nothing else, it is good practice to get used to using `* sizeof(whatever)` in your malloc() calls.

Comment: [Please don't cast the reutrn return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
char *src,*dest;

src=(char *)malloc(len(src)+1);
```

is undefined behavior, `src` is an uninitialized pointer which you can't pass to `len()` since it will read from it.

Also, `len()` is a re-implementation of `strlen()` but perhaps you knew that.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
src=(char *)malloc(len(src)+1);
```

Will error, as src has not been initialized yet.
Initialize it to some other value relevant to what it needs to be used for.

```
src=malloc(100); //for lack of any better value, used 100
```

Your function `len()` will error out if you pass it an uninitialized pointer .
And ***do not*** cast the return of `malloc()`

Answer (score 0):

When you malloc in your first line, you find the src size with len() but src is not initialized. So you malloc trash.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *src,*dest;
src=(char *)malloc(len(src)+1);
```

You forgot to add `-fclairvoyance` compiler option. Notice that clairvoyance is still in beta and is not guaranteed to produce correct results. To work around this limitation, try to estimate max string length up front:

```
src=malloc(100);
```

Note you should not cast the result of `malloc`.